# form in codeigniter not posting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a form in codeignitor and every time I try to submit something the page does nothing in chrome or in firefox gives me this message:

> The address wasn't understood
>
> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the
>   following protocols (localhost) isn't associated with any program or
>   is not allowed in this context.
>
> ```
> You might need to install other software to open this address.
> ```

In internet explorer it trys to find an application to open the page.

I can access the same address directly but it won't let me do it when I submit the form.

this is the code for the form:

```
<?php
$hidden = array('account_id' => '1');
echo form_open('post', '', $hidden); 
         ?>
        <label for="post">Post:</label>
       <input type="text" name="post" id="post"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="post" />
        </form>
```

This is the post controller:

```
<?php 

class Post extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
            {
                    parent::__construct();
                    $this->load->model('posts_model');
                    $this->load->helper('url_helper');
                    $this->load->helper('form');

            }

    function index() {
        $data['title'] = "posted";
        $this->posts_model->add_post();
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('comment/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }



}


?>
```

This is the function in the posts_model:

```
function add_post() {
    $data = array('person_acc_id' => $this-> input -> post('account_id'),
                  'post' => $this -> input -> post('post'),
                  'deleted' => 0,
                  'edited' => 0,
                  'post_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
    $this -> db -> insert('post', $data);
}
```

Comment: You may need to use codeigniter form validation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Is data being inserted into the database?
Are you sure the templates and the 'comment/index' views work?

Comment: I ran your code. Didn't attempt the insert - don't have your db schema. Instead I just did `var_dump($this->input->post(NULL, FALSE));` which showed all the expected data.Had to sub something else for the views in Post controller. Everything worked for me.

Comment: templates are working and I am able to access the view as well directly

Comment: Interesting. I can directly access the page http://localhost:8888/index.php/comment but when I try to submit the form and go to that page I get the error message The address wasn't understood

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (localhost) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

    You might need to install other software to open this address. Wasn't getting this in chrome (tried it in firefox)

Answer (score 1):

> Actually you didn't set any method to form. Means **your `form` action is Wrong**.

In your `function index()` **you call the view**. So  Then its load `from` in that. So if I click form submit `<form>` come to **`POST Controller`**. So it **again execute** `function index()` again. This will run like loop til you fix it.

So what you have to do is.

**In controller** Create new method to receive data

```
public function validate_form()
{
  #your Form validate Code goes here
}
```

**In view** `<form>` should be

```
echo form_open('post/validate_form', '', $hidden);
```

this will act like

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/post/validate_form" account_id="1" />
```

To Know about [Form Validation](http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-forms-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Just check your config.php in `application/config`, then change your link like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourApp/';
```

I guess your value before is like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/yourApp/';
```

Answer (score 0):

My code was actually fine. Once I put it on a real server it works. It would not work with localhost.